# Wordpress - How to find modifications after a post has been updated

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

Is there a way to find out which fields have been changed after someone updates a post in Wordpress?

The only way I figured out so far is using the `post_updated` hook:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/post_updated

That hook will return two objects: one containing all the fields before the update, and another one with the updated fields.

It is not the best option because that would require me to compare all the fields. I use WooCommerce, which adds a ton of extra meta fields to the posts, so processing all that data would take too much memory and time. I have to consider the scenario where the user is updating posts/products in mass, and also the fact that I will receive data from multiple stores.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Only process the fields that you want to process?

Comment: As @FrankerZ said, and manage your batch cases :-)

Comment: @FrankerZ that would be all fields, unfortunately. I'm writing a program to sync the entire catalog to an external server.